# UnfinishedStubbing Exception Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I Was trying to understand basics of testing using PowerMockito to mock static Method as I am new to this.
I am stuck as there is a very unusual situation If I use the below mentioned TestDrink.java I get the UnfinishedStubbingException.

But when I interchange doReurn..When with When..thenReturn Exception disappears.

**TestDrink.java**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Drink.class,Cola.class})
public class TestDrink {
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Cola.class);
        /*PowerMockito.when(Cola.drink())
                .thenReturn("Drinking");*/
        PowerMockito.doReturn("Drinking")
                .when(Cola.drink());
        System.out.println(Cola.drink());
    }
}
```

This is the class which I am trying to mock.

**Cola.java**

```
public class Cola {
    public static String drink()
    {
        return "No drinking";
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at TestDrink.test(TestDrink.java:22)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed


    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:124)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:63)
    at com.ayush.rock.Cola.gameOn(Cola.java)
    at TestDrink.test(TestDrink.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

If possible please try to give well-explained answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PowerMockito.doReturn("Drinking").when(Cola).drink();` ?

Comment: Currently using IntelliJ in ubuntu it doesn't allow me to use the way you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize `Cola.drink()` was a static method call. Try `BDDMockito.given(Cola.drink()).willReturn("Drinking");`

Comment: Yeah, that worked..But the issue is not that, issue is why above-mentioned way doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're calling to stub `Cola.drink()` is:

```
<T> T org.mockito.stubbing.Stubber.when(T mock)
```

The method expects a mock, not a real object. Your invocation, however, sends a real string:

```
PowerMockito.doReturn("Drinking").when(Cola.drink());
```

In the above line, the actual call is `...when("value returned by actual Cola.drink()")`

You can make it work by running:

```
BDDMockito.given(Cola.drink()).willReturn("Drinking");
```